# FFMPEG - How to add watermark picture in 2 videos overlayed

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor

I created a conference with 2 participants and both are recorded. After conference, I run FFMPEG to merge videos and creates the output.mp4.
It synchronizes the time, also.
I have a command that works fine:

> ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i vide2.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0]scale=iw/3:ih/3 [pip]; [1][pip] overlay=5:5;[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih[int];[int][1:v]overlay=W/2:2[vid];[0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" -map [vid] -map "[a]" -ac 2 -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -y -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4

I need to add two legends:

1 - Date and time at top center of the screen at all time of the video;

2 - Partipants name at bottom of the video.

I can create a file with this information before merging it.

Need a complete FFMPEG command line to have this.

Thanks

Comment: Is the command intended to produce 2 video streams for output?

Comment: Two input videos (conference) merged to output one video. I want the outputed video to have watermark ans legends (caption) with above informations, Thanks